# Indefinite article before group of nouns

Tags: indefinite-article

I wrote the following sentence in gmail:

> Please provide us with s184 certificate and invoice.

The auto grammar check suggested I insert "an" as below:

> Please provide us with **an** s184 certificate and invoice.

Is this correct? Do I use "an" and not "a" even though the noun "invoice" is not directly after the article? Or is it just an error in the program?

Comment: I think the software is assuming that you would pronounce the number of the certificate "ess one three four".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, yes - it sounds better with an article. There will be lots of "S184" certificates as it sounds like a standard certificate with a reference number and in this context, you are asking for one of them rather than a specific one, so the indefinite article is appropriate.

However, it is common to abbreviate language in business communications and I wouldn't have a problem with the sentence omitting the article, although if written that way I would prefer it to say "certificate S184":

> Please provide us with certificate S184 and invoice.

If you wanted to make the sentence grammatical rather than instructional then you might consider saying "please *can you* provide us with..."